# Android startActivityForResult and onActivityResult has unpredictable behaviours

Tags: java, android

I have an application in which multiple activities are shown in a certain order, which can change based on events in the current activity.  I have a "master" activity which manages which activities are shown.  Each ativity is started with `startActivityForResult()` with a `requestCode` unique to that activity.

When the activity finsishes, I set the `resultCode` to a value which will have meaning to the master activity. In the master activity's `onActivityResult` method, I have a `switch (requestCode)`, which will tell me which activity has returned, and in each case block I work with the `resultCode` to determine which activity to start next.

The problem I'm having, is that at times, seemingly randomly, the application behaves quite erratically, showing activities out of sequence.

I've been unable to replicate the issue while debugging, so all the information I have looks good, but the end users are constantly complaining about the erratic behaviour.

How can I test to see where the problem is?

---

The code from the master activity's onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case Settings.SCREEN_UPDATE:
        ShowActivity(LoginActivity.class, Settings.SCREEN_LOGIN);
        break;
    case Settings.SCREEN_LOGIN: 
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Settings.CurrentReport = new Report();
            Settings.CurrentReport.setUserId(data.getIntExtra("userId", -1));

            selectStore();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
        break;
    case Settings.SCREEN_PRODUCT: // Coming back from the product selection screen
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ShowActivity(ActionActivity.class, Settings.SCREEN_ACTION);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            ShowActivity(OptionsActivity.class, Settings.SCREEN_OPTIONS);
        }
        break;
    case Settings.SCREEN_ACTION: // Coming back from the action screen, regardless of result, show options screen.
        ShowActivity(OptionsActivity.class, Settings.SCREEN_OPTIONS);
        break;
    case Settings.SCREEN_OPTIONS: // All choices return result_ok.  Check the "mode" extra
        String mode = data.getStringExtra("mode");
        processOption(mode);
        break;
    case Settings.SCREEN_SESSION:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            ShowActivity(OptionsActivity.class, Settings.SCREEN_OPTIONS);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ){
            ShowActivity(ActionActivity.class, Settings.SCREEN_ACTION);
        }
        break;
    } // switch (requestCode)
} // protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

private void processOption(String mode) {
    if (mode.equals("select")) {
        ShowActivity(ProductActivity.class, Settings.SCREEN_PRODUCT);
    } else if (mode.equals("repeat")) {
        Settings.CurrentReport.repeatItem();
        ShowActivity(ActionActivity.class, Settings.SCREEN_ACTION);
    } else if (mode.equals("session")) {
        ShowActivity(SessionActivity.class, Settings.SCREEN_SESSION);
    } else { // mode equals "end"
        confirmFinish();
    }
}

private void ShowActivity(Class cls, int requestCode) {
    Intent activity = new Intent(this, cls);
    startActivityForResult(activity, requestCode);
}
```

---

Then, the code from one of the other activities handling the finish() event:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.options);

    Button btn;

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.putExtra("mode", "select");
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.putExtra("mode", "repeat");
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    btn.setEnabled(Settings.CurrentReport.hasPreviousItem());

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSession);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.putExtra("mode", "session");
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEnd);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.putExtra("mode", "end");
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            Intent i = getIntent();
            i.putExtra("mode", "end");
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();
            break;

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: How can we see where the problem is?

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code ?

Answer (score 0):

Im just guessing, but maybe `Intent intent = getIntent();` is causing the problems. You could try to replace it with `Intent intent = new Intent();`

getIntent() returns the intent that started the current activity and shouldn't be used as a result.

Comment: But isn't that what I want?  I want the intent that started the activity so that I have the correct requestCode.